# How to detect when pytest test case failed?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I am using pytest with selenium to automate a website. I want to take some screen shot only when a test case fails. I have previosly used TestNG and with TestNG it's quite east using the ITestListner.
Do we have something like that in pytest.

I have tried to achieve this using the teardown_method()
But this method is not getting executed when a test case fails.

```
import sys

from unittestzero import Assert
class TestPY:
    def setup_method(self, method):
        print("in setup method")
        print("executing " + method.__name__)

    def teardown_method(self, method):
        print(".....teardown")
        if sys.exc_info()[0]:
            test_method_name = method
            print test_method_name

    def test_failtest(self):
        Assert.fail("failed test")
```

`teardown_method()` get executed only when there are no fails

Comment: check the pytest hooks: https://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#post-process-test-reports-failures

Comment: @KirilS. thanks for the reply, I have tried that too and it seems that it's not working. I have user code from "Making test result information available in fixtures" section and my [codegist](https://gist.github.com/pr4bh4sh/29ca4da983d411bb2178)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to you [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35703122/how-to-detect-when-pytest-test-case-failed) on stackoverflow, I can share that I is something on my mind, I hope it will help:wink:
What you're trying to do is to handle standard *AssertionError* exception that can be raised by *[**assert**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingAssertionsEffectively)* keyword or by any assertion method implemented in [unittest.TestCase](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/unittest.html#classes-and-functions) or maybe any custom assertion method that raises custom exception.
There are 3 ways to do that:

1. Use *[try-except-finally](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)* construction. Some basic example:

   > ```
   > try:
   >     Assert.fail("failed test")
   > except AssertionError:
   >     get_screenshot()
   >     raise
   > ```
2. Or use ***with*** statement, as context manager:

   > ```
   > class TestHandler:
   >     def __enter__(self):
   >         #  maybe some set up is expected before assertion method call
   >         pass
   >
   >     def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
   >         #  catch whether exception was raised
   >         if isinstance(exc_val, AssertionError):
   >             get_screenshot()
   >
   >
   > with TestHandler():
   >     Assert.fail("failed test")
   > ```
   >
   > [here](http://preshing.com/20110920/the-python-with-statement-by-example/) you can dive deeper on how to play with it
3. The last one, in my opinion, is the most elegant approach. Using [decorators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). With this decorator you can decorate any testing method:

   > ```
   > def decorator_screenshot(func):
   >     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
   >         try:
   >            func(*args, **kwargs)
   >         except AssertionError:
   >            get_screenshot()
   >            raise
   >     return wrapper
   >
   >
   > @decorator_screenshot
   > def test_something():
   >     Assert.fail("failed test")
   > ```

Comment: "with" is working fine as of now and finally I'm able to do what I actually intended to do. And Sorry I'm not able to upvote because of low reputation.

Comment: I will also dive into decorator's once I get time.

Comment: Glad it helped! Don't worry about upvoting, my attempt was to help, not being upvoted)

Answer (score 8):

After some struggle, eventually this worked for me.

In conftest.py:

```
@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True, tryfirst=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    rep = outcome.get_result()
    setattr(item, "rep_" + rep.when, rep)
    return rep
```

And, in your code, in a fixture (e.g., in a teardown fixture for tests) use it like so:

```
def tear_down(request):
    method_name = request.node.name
    if request.node.rep_call.failed:
        print('test {} failed :('.format(method_name))
        # do more stuff like take a selenium screenshot
```

Note that "request" is a fixture "funcarg" that pytest provides in the context of your tests. You don't have to define it yourself.

Sources: [pytest examples](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/simple.html#making-test-result-information-available-in-fixtures) and [thread on (not) making this easier](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/issues/230).

Answer (score 1):

This is how we do it , note **__multicall__** has very less documentation and I remember reading **__multicall__** is going to be deprecated, please use this with a pinch of salt and experiment with replacing **__multicall__** with '**item, call**' as per the examples.

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(__multicall__):
    report = __multicall__.execute()

    if report.when == 'call':
        xfail = hasattr(report, 'wasxfail')
        if (report.skipped and xfail) or (report.failed and not xfail):

           try:
              screenshot = APP_DRIVER.take_screen_shot(format="base64")


           except Exception as e:
              LOG.debug("Error saving screenshot !!")
              LOG.debug(e)

    return report
```

Comment: The supported version of doing the same thing is decorating this with `@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)` and using `outcome = yield; report = outcome.get_result()` instead of `__multicall__` (which will trigger a pytest warning since 2.8)

Comment: __multicall__ funcarg is indeed deprecated. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    if call.when == 'call':
        if call.excinfo is not None:
            # if excinfor is not None, indicate that this test item is failed test case
            error("Test Case: {}.{} Failed.".format(item.location[0], item.location[2]))
            error("Error: \n{}".format(call.excinfo))
```

Comment: Please explain how your code example answers the question and how it should be integrated into the asker's code sample.